# iPhone cameras roll buffering before playback

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, video, photos.app

Every time I go to watch a video or see a photo on my phone, the little white circle appears  in the middle of the media and I have to wait while it buffers now.

[image]

This is NOT to do with the iCloud.  I don’t have any of the photos of videos online and I don’t have the camera roll online for it to download.

Now from my best guess of what’s happening, is that when my phone was recently full, I ran out of space, the phone compressed all the videos and pictures as a self defense mechanism.

But I’ve deleted a whole bunch of stuff and made plenty of space now.

How do I get the phone to decompress the camera roll now? Or if that is not correct, how do I get the video/ photo immediately ?

Comment: Can you get a capture if this UI so people can understand what you're seeing? this will be hard to troubleshoot without being over your shoulder to look. Also - how do you know it's not iCloud? It sure sounds like that to me, but I can't tell without seeing what you see and knowing what you know. Just edit this post which will get a review to see if it's answerable with an edit.

Comment: @bmike the circle is the same as the one that appears in menu bar when cellular data is used. I've seen it but then I just went to macOS to watch the video, so idk how to fix it. OP can try a restart though.

Comment: Let’s reopen @ankii if you get what’s being asked